# How can I rename my .xcodeproj without it crashing?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've looked all over the internet and tried everything I could possibly think of to change a .xcodeproj name - for example: http://prntscr.com/6xrms6

But it all just crashes Xcode and then when I reopen it, my app breaks completely.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe... ? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html

Comment: That's what I'm doing and it keeps crashing...

Answer (score 1):

Use Bash and regular expressions to change all occurrences of old project name to new project name.

```
SRCROOT='path/to/repo' # 1
find "$SRCROOT" -type f -not -regex '.*/\.git/.*' -not -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'file="{}"; sed -E -i "" "s/OldProjectName/NewProjectName/g" "$file"' # 2
find -E "$SRCROOT" -type f -regex '.*OldProjectName.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'src="{}"; dst=$(echo "$src" | sed -E "s/OldProjectName/NewProjectName/g"); mkdir -p "$(dirname "$dst")"; mv "$src" "$dst"' # 3
```

Explanation:

1. Path containing `OldProjectName.xcodeproj`
2. Change occurrences of "OldProjectName" to "NewProjectName" in contents of desired files
3. Rename files to replace occurrences of "OldProjectName" with "NewProjectName" in file paths

**NOTE**: You will likely need to edit these regex's to fit your specific needs. If you only want to rename your project but not all the targets and/or class names, then you will need to get crafty with the regex's you use.

Also, I assume you already tried clicking to rename the project and that didn't work for some reason...

[image: Click to rename project]